# Tuning mongoDB lookup

Tags: mongodb, performance, lookup

I have a aggregate that in first stage use $lookup for join tow collection and
then use $skip and $limit.But it's so slow.
If i put the $lookup after $skip and $limit in my aggregate pipeline,
does it any effect in performance of my aggregate query?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Please show us what you've trued

Comment: i have tried this but at present i have few valid data.differences is not tangible.

Answer (score 0):

Your query's slow performance is most probably because of [skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/). Aggregation `$skip` has no info about that on its page but the link I share says that `skip` has performance issues. Most probably aggregation skip has that too.

For your question, you should filter as much as possible before any lookup/join for any database. So unnecessary documents/data will not be get into ram. But like I said most probably it will not make your query so much faster.

Comment: does $lookup requires to  walk though all the documents for join?

Comment: @Masoudjf, as far as I know it can use indexes if the lookup fields are indexed. But other unidexed fields of lookuped document has to be get via scan. And real issue here is that; if you will filter some of the joined documents in next stages, filter them first.